# Terraform redeploys existing resources

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm deploying Azure diagnostics settings with Terraform and for some reason the resources get destroyed and recreated on every deployment. What do I need to add so it skips the destroy/create if it already exists ?

```
data "external" "aks_nsg_id" {
  program = [
    "bash",
    "${path.root}/scripts/aks_nsg_id.sh"
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "aksnsg" {
  name                       = "aksnsg-ds"
  target_resource_id         = "${data.external.aks_nsg_id.result.output}"
  storage_account_id         = "${var.storage_account}"
  log_analytics_workspace_id = "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics.id}"

  log {
    category = "NetworkSecurityGroupRuleCounter"
    enabled  = true

    retention_policy {
      enabled = true
      days    = 365
    }
  }

  log {
    category = "NetworkSecurityGroupEvent"
    enabled  = true

    retention_policy {
      enabled = true
      days    = 365
    }
  }

  depends_on = [data.external.aks_nsg_id]
}
```

The bash script, which gets the NSG ID is as follows:

```
OUTPUT=$(az network nsg list --query [].id -o tsv | grep aks | head -n 1)
jq -n --arg output "$OUTPUT" '{"output":$output}'
```

```
[0m[1mazurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting.aksnsg: Destruction complete after 53s[0m[0m
...........
[0m[1mazurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting.aksnsg: Creation complete after 2s
```

Terraform apply 2nd run forces replacement, even though it exists:

```
azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting.aksnsg must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "aksnsg" {
      ~ id                         = "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/MC_terraform-aks-rg_terraform-aks_westeurope/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/aks-agentpool-32800724-nsg|aksnsg-ds" -> (known after apply)
        log_analytics_workspace_id = "/subscriptions/.../resourcegroups/terraform-marius-oms-rg/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/terraform-oms"
        name                       = "aksnsg-ds"
        storage_account_id         = "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/terraform-oms-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/archivingsaaccount001"
      ~ target_resource_id         = "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/MC_terraform-aks-rg_terraform-aks_westeurope/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/aks-agentpool-32800724-nsg" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
```

Comment: We need to see the relevant Terraform output for why the resource is determined to be unique during the execution.

Comment: Also a plan would be useful

Comment: I'm thinking this is happening because Terraform is not aware of the network security group, meaning it wasn't deployed with Terraform and is not present in the state file. I tried adding a lifecycle to ignore it, but it's not supported for azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting

Comment: First, I would recommend using a data-resource in Terraform to fetch the NSG-id:
data "azurerm_network_security_group" "example" {
  name                = "example"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

Next, I think you need to look at the output as Matt says. It might be that Azure makes a change to the resource without your knowledge and that this parameter forces replacement of the resource when you deploy. The output will show this, if it's the case. You can add a lifecycle meta-argument with "ignore_changes" to prevent it from re-deploying that way.